# javascript objects, what could be wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial on Codecademy and it says

> unexpected token {

What is the error here please?

This is what I need to do

> Write an if statement that checks to see if suitcase has the shorts property.
>
> If your if statement evaluates to true, print the value of the shorts property.
>
> If your if statement evaluates to false, set the shorts property to any value you wish using dot notation. Then print the value of the shorts property.

```
var suitcase = {
    shirt: "Hawaiian"
};
if (suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts") {
        console.log(suitcase.shorts)
    } else if (suitcase.hasOwnProperty != ("shorts")) {
        suitcase = {
            shorts: "tailormade"
        };
        console.log(suitcase.shorts);
    }
}
```

Comment: i mean i know its saying unexpected { but i dont see an unexpected {

Comment: That's not how function calls work...

Comment: `if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts"){`. You have not closed the parenthesis.

Comment: Check this line `if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty!=("shorts")` you should remove `!=`

Comment: @RtrRtr Use something like http://jslint.com to proof these as they provide a bit more verbatim detail on errors and allows you to debug as fast as you can type until valid.

Comment: If you have mutually exclusive values, there is not need to test for the false option so simply remove `if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty!=("shorts")`

Answer (score 4):

```
var suitcase = {
     shirt: "Hawaiian"
     };

     if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")){

      console.log(suitcase.shorts);


     }else if(!suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")){

     suitcase = { shorts: "tailormade"};
      console.log(suitcase.shorts);


    }
```

Things that changed:

```
 if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts"){
```

Was missing parenthesis

```
 if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")){
```

And this:

```
}else if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty!=("shorts")){
```

Removed `!=` and moved `!` in front.

```
}else if(!suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")){
```

Do note, that you could just say `else`, there's no need for an `else if`. I also removed the last closing bracket and added one semi-colon after the first `console.log`. And since you're doing `console.log(suitcase.shorts);` in both places, just move it out of the conditionals all together.

So we could further reduce this code to this:

```
var suitcase = {
     shirt: "Hawaiian"
     };
 if(!suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")){
     suitcase = { shorts: "tailormade"};
    }
console.log(suitcase.shorts);
```

Comment: +1, this is the only answer that fix both problems in this code

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, how do i do this what is wrong with this code.

Comment: var nyc = {
    fullName: "New York City",
    mayor: "Michael Bloomberg",
    population: 8000000,
    boroughs: 5
};

// write your for-in loop here
 for( var "population" in nyc){
     
     console.log(population);
 }

Comment: I think he wants to ADD the shorts, not replace the shirt

Comment: If you want to add something, say `suitcase["shorts"] = "tailormade";`

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code:

```
if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts"){
```

Is missing 1 more parenthesis to close the if statement. It should read:

```
if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")){
```

You also have an extra ending brace at the very end of the code you pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is missing a `)` - whenever you get an "unexpected something" error, always count your parentheses. It helps to use an editor that supports bracket matching, such as Notepad++.